# Error "unhandled socket.io url" with python as client

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, socket.io

I am new to Nodejs and using socket.io. But when i connect through python client i am geting error **unhandled socket.io url**

**Python code**

**client.py**

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
with SocketIO("192.168.1.191", 8001) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit("answer", {"mess":"jdfjdn"})
```

**Server.js**

```
var ioSocket = require('socket.io').listen(8001, { log: true });
console.log('connect');
ioSocket.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('answer', function (data) {
        console.log('answer');
    });
});
```

When i run test.py i get the error **"unhandled socket.io url"**

Answer (score 0):

> As your websocket server is running on 192.168.1.191 IP and your client socket sending request to localhost(127.0.0.1),So you need to change either 192.168.1.191 to 127.0.0.1 or you need to modify client code to send request to particular IP

Modify client JS code as

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, ipAddress);
var socket = io.listen(server);
```

Enter IP address and port no you want.

Comment: thank you for answer, i am using python client and even if i give localhost as address i am getting same error

Comment: did you tried changing ip address in to client code